# Cant bind complex property to gridview with entity framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, gridview

I have the following code which should bind some data to a gridview but its not working.

THe district manager object has a Brand.
As you can see in the screenshot the brand is correctly filled in with data.

```
 private void LoadData()
        {
            List<DealerDistrictManager> listDealerDistrictManager = DistrictManagerBL.GetAllDealersWithDistrictManagers();
            DistrictManagersGrid.DataSource = listDealerDistrictManager;
            DistrictManagersGrid.DataBind();


     <asp:BoundColumn DataField="DistrictManagerId" Visible="False"></asp:BoundColumn> 
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Brand.Name" meta:resourcekey="BrandHeader"></asp:BoundColumn>


 public class DealerDistrictManager
    {
        public int DistrictManagerId { get; set; }
        public string Nuteres { get; set; } 
        public string DealerNumber { get; set; }
        public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }
        public int DistrictNumber { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

 public class Brand
    {
        public int BrandId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

**Update1**

```
public List<DealerDistrictManager> GetAllDealersWithDistrictManagers()
    {

            return  (from d in _context.Dealers
                      from m in _context.DistrictManagers
                      where d.Nuteres == m.DealerNuteres
                     select new DealerDistrictManager
                                { 
                                    DistrictManagerId= m.DistrictManagerId,
                                    Nuteres = d.Nuteres,
                                    DealerNumber = d.DealerNumber,
                                    Brand  = m.Brand,
                                    DistrictNumber = m.DistrictNumber,
                                    Name = m.Name

                                 }).ToList<DealerDistrictManager>(); 

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Now wouldn't it be a tad easier to prepare a view model and then map the Entity model to the view model via e.g. AutoMapper? You could 'flatten' the view model class and possibly avoid this error altogether. :) But more on topic, you could try to eager-load the Brands and see if the error is still there.

Comment: view model? automapper? I dont understand, we want to avoid complex code in here. Any easier way?

Comment: I updated the question with the code that gets the data from the context.

Comment: I'm not very experienced in ASP but can this be done in ASP: <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Brand.Name"...>. I know this is possible in WPF databinding scenarios. You have a main object and "navigate" to a property on an inherited class. Sure for ASP that this can be done?

Comment: @YoupTube thats exactly what I did, if you check my markup code, but its not working, the weird thing is that in another page I have the same scenario but with different objects and it binds the data correctly to the grid.

Comment: I know that that was what you exactly did. I just wanted to know if this construct is feasible in ASP.NET... but you say it is because in another sceanrio it just works fine. Ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236900/eval-versus-datafield-in-aspdatagrid) also speaks about the same / similar problem. Where it "randomly" occurs. The solution that the questioner found was to use:

```
<%#Eval("contentsection.Id") %>
```

The post mentioned has a lot of answers (including an accepted one) that will clarify a lot I presume.

Comment: Yep. Weird is it! But you forget the weirdness and will become happy with the result, I hope ;)